# Selecting a specific record from a Java Derby Database

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

How would I actually display a single record from a database with the record fields being displayed in related `TextFields`.
I've tried below but I select either of them and it only shows one record, where have I gone wrong?

```
String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
Class.forName(driver);
String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/NoteDatabase";
String uName = "Simon";
String uPass = "Password";

Connection con = getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt = con.createStatement();

stmt.executeQuery(" select * from " + lstGetItems.getSelectedValue() + "");
ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
if (rs.next()) {
    txtNoteTitle.setText(rs.getString("NOTENAME"));
    txtTextInput.setText(rs.getString(2));
```

Which gets me the below result. As in the screenshot 
[image]

I tried this to fix but all I get is an exception when I click on the same note.

```
String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
Class.forName(driver);
String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/NoteDatabase";
String uName = "Simon";
String uPass = "Password";

Connection con = getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt = con.createStatement();

stmt.executeQuery(" select * from " + lstGetItems.getSelectedValue() + " WHERE 'NOTENAME' = " + lstGetNotes.getSelectedValue() + " ");
ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
if (rs.next()) {
    txtNoteTitle.setText(rs.getString("NOTENAME"));
    txtTextInput.setText(rs.getString("NOTECONENT"));
```

[image]

Comment: Don't, ever, use concatenation to pass parameter values to a SQL query. Use prepared statements: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of Select is [sql select](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp):

```
SELECT column1, column2, ... FROM table_name;
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

---

So in your case if you want to select from a specific table **(lstGetItems.getSelectedValue())** that is entered by the user then you have to check if your table name exist or not before you make your select.

If you want to select from your table with WHERE `something = somethingelse` your second query is not correct because you miss to put your String between two `''` and remove the two `''` from the name of your column so instead you have to use:

```
stmt.executeQuery(" select * from "+ lstGetItems.getSelectedValue() +" WHERE NOTENAME = '" + lstGetNotes.getSelectedValue() + "' " );
```

---

I consider that `lstGetItems.getSelectedValue()` is your table name.
and  `NOTENAME` is your column name.
and that `lstGetNotes.getSelectedValue()` the value of your column.

But your way is not secure and can cause an error syntax of SQL Injection so instead you have to use PreparedStatement

---

**EDIT**

For example :

```
try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
        "select * from table_name WHERE NOTENAME = ?")) {
    stmt.setString(1, lstGetNotes.getSelectedValue());

    ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
    if (result.next()) {
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: you are welcom @Dajan3

Comment: Please do use the PreparedStatement technique. Concatenating strings to form your SQL is a very bad practice and you should break that habit immediately.

Comment: @BryanPendleton maybe i don't get you, but, i suggest to use PreparedStatement with values and not with name of table or schema or database, is that what you mean?

Comment: I correct the OP's  way, and i mention where he get the error, and in the end i said that the good practice is to use PreparedStatement right? @BryanPendleton i already makes an example in the end ;)

Comment: Thank you! Your revised example is good practice! My original comment was directed at the OP, not at you, so I was agreeing with your advice to always use PreparedStatement with placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

1 : read the exception: no column Hello2 ...

2 : select * from must be followed by a table name, not by a value :  lstGetItems.getSelectedValue()